# How do you import a module that may have syntax errors in it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, require

I have two scripts `a.js` & `b.js`. `b.js` may have syntax errors in it. How can I account for this?

**a.js**

```
let codeForRunning = require('b.js');

try {
    resultOfCode = codeForRunning.func(TEST);
}
catch (err) {
    resultOfCode = err
}
```

---

**b.js**

```
function myFunction (argument) {
    return 'Hello world
}

module.exports = { func: saveWrittenCode }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require the module on a try / catch block:

```js
try {
    const b = require('./b');
    // Code
} catch (err) {
   console.log('Module b could not be loaded');
}
```

Another alternative is to load the module as a text and evaluate in runtime:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const b = fs.readFileSync('./b.js', 'utf8');

try {
    const evaluated = eval(b);
    // Code
} catch (err) {
   console.log('Module b could not be loaded');
}
```

Obs: Be sure that the code you will evaluate is trustworthy, or else you will be vulnerable to Remote Code Execution